# Path to executable on Install Delphi Service

Tags: delphi, windows-services

Is there any way to put the executable path of Delphi service in double quotes?

I have created a Delphi service and install it by using /install parameter.

If I look via Windows Services, properties, the Path to executable is not enclosed in double quotes.

How to do this in Delphi way?

I am using Delphi 7 and Windows 2012.

Comment: Why would you feel any requirement to use quotes here? Are you including arguments to the command line for your service?

Comment: I've come across this too, there is an exploit where the service name is unquoted
https://www.commonexploits.com/unquoted-service-paths/

Answer (score 3):

`TService` does not support customizing the install path during installation time. You have to use the `TService.AfterInstall` event to edit the Registry directly. You can use `ParamStr(0)` to get the executable path and then add double quotes to it using `AnsiQuotedStr()`.

```
procedure TMyService.ServiceAfterInstall(Sender: TService);
var
  Reg: TRegistry;
begin
  Reg := TRegistry.Create;
  try
    Reg.RootKey := HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
    Reg.Access := KEY_SET_VALUE;
    if Reg.OpenKey('\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\'+Sender.Name, False) then
    try
      Reg.WriteString('ImagePath', AnsiQuoutedStr(ParamStr(0), '"'));
    finally
      Reg.CloseKey;
    end;
  finally
    Reg.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Does this take care of 32 bit OS as well? I think the registry location would be different.

Comment: @ewlung no, it is not different. HKLM\System is not split into separate 32bit and 64bit keys